# Can I install TextMate 2 and keep TextMate 1?

Tags: development, textmate

I would like to try TextMate's new version but since it is a beta release with some bugs and unfinished features, I don't want to use it everyday. Is there any way to install TextMate 2 and keep Textmate 1?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use /Applications or ~/Applications, you can put text mate 2 in any folder you wish.

For example if you have Textmate in /Applications/Textmate.app, create a folder in /Applications/TM2/Textmate2.app

Answer (score 0):

Put TextMate 2 in ~/Applications and Textmate 1 in /Applications then. As I remember, they use the different folders in App Support